# onfocusout for an event..alert got stucked into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added an `onfocusout` attribute to my HTML tag and I added an alert in the function but the alert function is running infinite loop as it is out of focus of that element.

How to close that alert at once?

eg:

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="a" onfocusout="hello()" name="name" />
  <script>
    function hello(){
      var x= document.getElementById("a").value.length;
      if("x<6"){
         alert("minimum 6 digits");
         document.getElementById("a").value='';
         document.getElementById("a").focus();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is similar to this which run infinite alert.

Comment: don't use `alert` & `focus` because you won't let the user to leave the page...

Comment: `if("x<6")` is **always true**. Use `if(x<6)`

Answer (score 2):

this behavior is happening because when you use `focus` it will re attach the `focusout` event handler. So what you have to do, first is to remove the `focusout` event handler, and attach it again when your condition is `true`

```
if(x < 6){
  alert("minimum 6 digits");
  $("#a").val('');
  $("#a").off("focusout");
  $("#a").focus();
  $("#a").on("focusout", hello);
}
```

furthermore, this is not enough. because after you set the value of input with ID 'a' to '', when you reattach the event, it will keep going inside your condition, because the current value is '' (which means its length is 0), and will keep reattach your event handler. So, you need another global variable to check, whether current status is checking, or no

```
var check = false;
```

then you need to check that variable each time you want to re attach your event handler, if its false (means currently its not checking), then you can reattach. but will re attach, you set that variable to true. After finish re attaching, then you set that variable back to false.

```
  if (check == false)
  {
    if(x < 6){
      check = true;
      alert("minimum 6 digits");
      $("#a").val('');
      $("#a").off("focusout");
      $("#a").focus();
      $("#a").on("focusout", hello);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    check = false;
  }
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/t3aoenvd/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="a" onfocusout="hello()" name="name" />
        <script>
        function hello(){
             var x= document.getElementById("a").value.length;
             if(x < 6){
                     alert("minimum 6 digits");
                     document.getElementById("a").value='';
                     document.getElementById("a").focus();
             }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes sir , but when we try to close the alert box by pressing ok, again the event will call hello function as it is out of focus , again alert will pop and it runs infinte.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way is to use `setTimeout()` after `alert()`. For the post question example:

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="a" onfocusout="hello()" name="name" />

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function hello(){

          let x = document.getElementById("a").value.length;

          if(x < 6){                 
             document.getElementById("a").value='';

             alert("minimum 6 digits");     
             setTimeout(() => { 
               document.getElementById('a').focus();
             }, "100")

          }
        }

      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```